# Contextual word embeddings from pretrained word2vec vectors

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, text-classification

I would like to create word embeddings that take **context** into account, so the vector of the word *Jaguar [animal]* would be different from the word *Jaguar [car brand]*.

As you know, word2vec only gives one representation for a given word, and I would like to take already pretrained embeddings and enrich them with context. So far I've tried a simple way with taking an average vector of the word and category word, for example [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtMaT.png).

Now I would like to try to create and train a neural network that would take entire sentences, e.g.

1. *Jaguar F-PACE is a great SUV sports car.*
2. *Among cats, only tigers and lions are bigger than jaguars.*

And then it would undertake the task of text classification (I have a dataset with several categories like animals, cars, etc.), but the result would be new representations for the word jaguar, but in different contexts, so two different embeddings.

Does anyone have any idea how I could create such a network? I don't hide that I'm a beginner and have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: First, SO is for programming questions, ML design question can be asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. This question is actually about [a complex research problem](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=contextual+embedding+word+sense) which involves not only word embeddings and context but also word sense disambiguation. The first problem is this: how would the model understand how many different embeddings are needed for a given word? I would suggest starting with something simpler before addressing research questions which can easily be a full PhD topic ;)

Comment: To simplify the whole thing, I'm assuming a limited number of embeddings per word, I have a dataset of a dozen words - each word has two/three meanings and each meaning has dozens of sentences - a small dataset initially, as the whole work is heavily experimental.

Comment: You mean that your data is already organized for a limited subset of ambiguous words, with their sense identified?

Comment: Exactly! So I'm looking for supervised method of word embeddings creation (or rather modification of pretrained ones)

Comment: ok, I see. I think it's going to be the same as the regular method then, you just pass your sense-specific contexts instead of all the contexts for the training. The traditional method is [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec), but I'm not very familiar with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already been able to perform sense-disambiguation outside word2vec, then you can change the word-tokens to reflect your external judgement. For example, change some appearances of the token `'jaguar'` to `'jaguar*car'` and others to `'jaguar*animal'`. Proceeding with normal word2vec training will then get your two different tokens two different word-vectors.

If you're hoping for the training to discover these itself, as ~Erwan mentioned in a comment, that seems like an open research question, without a standard or off-the-shelf solution that a beginner could drop-in.

I'd once seen a paper (around the time of the original word2vec papers, but can't find the link now) that tried to do this in a word2vec-compatible way by 1st proceeding with traditional polysemy-oblivious training. Then, for every appearance of a word X, model its surrounding context via some combination of the word-vectors of neighbors within a certain number of positions. (That in itself is very similar to the preparation of a context-vector in the CBOW mode of word2vec.) Perform some clustering on that collection-of-all-contexts to come up with some idea of alternate senses – each associated with one cluster. Then, in a followup pass on the original corpus, replace word-tokens with those that also reflect their nearby-context cluster. (EG: `'jaguar'` might be replaced with `'jaguar*1'`, `'jaguar*2'`, etc based on which discrete cluster its context suggested.) Then, repeat (or continue) word2vec training to get sense-specific word-vectors. Of course, the devil would be in the details of how contexts are defined, how clusters are deduced, and tough edge-cases (where potentially the text's author is themselves deploying the multiple senses).

Some other interesting efforts to model or deduce polysemy in word2vec models:

- ["Linear Algebraic Structure of Word Meanings"](http://www.offconvex.org/2016/07/10/embeddingspolysemy/)
- ["A Simple Approach to Learn Polysemous Word Embeddings"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01793)

But per above, I've not seen these sorts of techniques widely implemented/adopted in a form that's easy to drop-in to another project.